# How to make sure that a job runs only once / or only by one of the 5 load balancer servers

Tags: java

Problem :There are 5 load balancers in Production environment, so basically my application is running in 5 servers / load balancers.
I have a job, which runs exactly at 10 o clock in the morning, send notifications to actual users based on some business checks.
now, that I have 5 load balancers, how to make sure that this job runs only once/ or only by one of the 5 servers.

Comment: Just run it on one server? What does load balancing have to do with job scheduling?

Comment: I think you will need another load balancer for the other load balancers...

Comment: @shmosel, the job is part of the application - a spring quartz job, which uses a time property that we supply from application.properties file (the time property for spring quartz is similar to the cron job property in linux) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using quartz scheduler, you can achieve this.

Below is a explaination on how quartz does this ?

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html